# Laravel validation on multiple insert

Tags: laravel, validation, vue.js, laravel-5

I have a db table of sport events. Each event has a year, event name and an event winner.

My admin view for this table allows the events to be grouped by year and inserted in bulk (generally 8 sports events rows at once). I have a table, written in Vue that allows up to 8 sports events rows to be added to the interface, fields populated and submitted. This works *well*.

The method for this is

```
public function storeMultiple(Request $request)
    {

        $year = $request->year;
        $newEvents = $request->events;

        foreach ($newEvents as $key => $value) {
            DB::table('sport_events')->insert([
                'team_id' => 1,
                'sort_order' => $value['sort_order'],
                'year' => $year,
                'event' => $value['event'],
                'winner' => $value['winner'],
                'created_at' => Carbon::now(),
                'updated_at' => Carbon::now()
            ]);
        }

    }
```

While I know it's not a great way (the db structure limits me here rather than having year be the key and sport events within) and for such a small and infrequent use case, I'm happy with the performance trade off.

The form is submitted to my route via Axios and everything lands in the database as I'd expect.

Now I'm looking to add validation to the method, ensuring that each event has event name and the winner.

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'year' => 'required',
            'events.*' => 'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json([ 'errors' => $validator ]);
        }
```

It seems that my submit bypasses the validation checks that I have in place, getting a success status.

My Vue submit method does this

```
submit () {
                axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/admin/sports',
                    data: {
                        year: this.year,
                        sports: this.sports
                    }
                }).then((response) => {
            window.location.href = '/admin/sports'

                }).catch((error) => {
                    // error
                })
            }
```

Where am I going wrong in this method?

UPDATE: Thiago's suggestion resolved things but I then had to update the submit method within my Vue component to get erroring to display

```
submit () {
                axios({
                    method: 'post',
                    url: '/admin/sports',
                    data: {
                        year: this.year,
                        sports: this.sports
                    }
                }).then((response) => {
                    window.location.href = '/admin/sports'
                }).catch((error) => {
                    this.errors = error.response.data.errors
                    console.log(this.errors)
                })
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'year' => 'required',
    'events.*.event' => 'required',
    'events.*.winner' => 'required',
]);
```

What do you mean in your question text by "getting a success status"?

Does the data get into the DB, or you just mean that the AJAX call returned successfully?

To fail the AJAX request use:

```
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return response()
        ->json([ 'errors' => $validator->errors()->messages() ])
        ->setStatusCode(400);
}
```

Comment: nope, still bypasses validation. Even simplifying it by just trying to validate that the year exists - removing the array of events, still fails :(

Comment: just that the AJAX call returned successfully and redirected me to where it should if data does get passed `/admin/costs`. So that works a little better now in that it doesn't redirect but I don't see the errors getting passed back.

Comment: Laravel does not do this automatically. In order to do that you will need to read the errors from the response and show the errors via JS. Maybe this can help you: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/showing-request-validation-errors-when-submitting-form-by-ajax

Comment: Thanks Thiago - got it sorted now 